# Change permission for IBM liberty server logs

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I have liberty server running on redhat linux for my java batch application. When I liberty start server, logs gets generated with the permission of 640(messages.log). My splunk configuration not able to access this logs and expects 755 permission. what is the configuration change required to change log file permission to 755.

I have tried changing server.env with the below parameter. But didn't work as expected.
     `WLP_SKIP_UMASK=true
 LogFilePermissions=755`

Comment: Did you set a permissive umask (022?) before running bin/server? 
Did you delete messages.log before restarting?   umask applies to newly created files.

Comment: Yes. I removed the previously generated logs and set the umask to true. Then started the server. Also, I believe this change will not have any impact to the sublogs folders such as joblogs and ffdc logs folder

Comment: "umask to true" isn't sufficient. You mean the environment variable, but you still need to check/set your actual umask to something permissive to result in any kind of change.  What's your umask when the logs have unexpected permissions?